# Algorithm for maximizing AX subject to BX=0

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I am given two arrays A and B of n numbers (not necessarily positive), indexed from 1 to n.

I am asked to compute an array X of n numbers between 0 and 1 (inclusive) that maximizes

`A[1]×X[1] + ... + A[n]×X[n]`

subject to

`B[1]×X[1] + ... + B[n]×X[n] = 0`

Is there a standard algorithm for solving this problem?

I searched for linear programming and for the knapsack problem, but none of them seems to fit.

Comment: This is a very very natural LP. The specific form depends on the solvers API. In most solvers APIs, your problem boils down to: 1) Declare n variables 2) Set bounds to [0, 1] for your n variables 3) Set objective vector to your A (n coeffs -> exactly your A) 4) Add a single constraint based on B (n coeffs -> exactly B) equal to value zero. 5) Ask for maximization. 6) Solve | With canonical LP: `min c.T*x | st. A*x=b | x>=0`, your `a` is `c.T` and `A` is a matrix with a single row equal to your array `b`. `b` is a col-vector of size 1 with an entry of 0. Extra rows in A could encode bounds.

Comment: Could you point me to a solver that accepts this kind of input? (`min c.T*x | st. A*x=b  and x>=0 and x<=1`)

Comment: That should not be your top priority. Your priority should be focused on how accessible the solver (or modelling system) is. If you, for whatever reason, would need to build CoinOR Clp from sources on windows, you will give up immediately. I also wouldn't focus on this low-lvl form. Your task is so trivial, that every solver-API should be usable without any trouble. So pick Clp, glpk, ortools glop, Highs, lp_solve, ... whatever. Either by their wrappers in various programming-languages or by somehow generating LP/MPS input. Some even have a math-language they support (but i don't use those).

Comment: If you know python you probably would achieve a small demo within minutes using one of python-mip, pulp, pyomo, scipy, ortools, cvxpy or cvxopt (all modelling libraries bringing some solvers). Even if i wouldn't recommend the form you ask for, scipy's is more or less exactly that [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html). But people often prefer the others because of the potential overhead using this low-lvl form.

Comment: I will take a look. Apart from these sophisticated tools, do you think a greedy algorithm is possible?